# Scala - Need help in accessing each row of a specific column like x(i+1) and x(i-1)

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a spark data frame, where I have few columns as tin, year, date_begin, date_end, continuous_data

```
    tin   year    continuous_data
    a1    2017          0
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          0
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          0
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          1
    a1    2017          0
    a1    2017          1
```

similarly I have 2 more columns which is of date-time format as (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss).

I need to access each rows of 'continuous_data' column, like x(i+1) and x(i-1). In my case its like

continuous_data(i) - current row value
continuous_data(i-1) - previous row value
continuous_data(i+1) - next row value

so that my need would be like below

```
    tin   year    continuous_data    prev_data    next_data
    a1    2017          0                null        1
    a1    2017          1                0           0
    a1    2017          0                1           1
    a1    2017          1                0           1    
    a1    2017          1                1           0
    a1    2017          0                1           1
    a1    2017          1                0           1
    a1    2017          1                1           1
    a1    2017          1                1           0
    a1    2017          0                1           1
    a1    2017          1                0           null
```

I need to solve it in pure Scala, instead of using spark functions, where I achieved it using window functions which is not required for some reasons.
I'm trying to solve this from past few days, but I couldn't resolve it yet. Could someone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, why can't you use window functions? Regular scala collections have `sliding` function, but datasets don't and easiest way to solve it would be with just using window  functions.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik, yes, that's the easiest way and I have done that as well, though it was ok, I must need to implement the same with pure scala script, specially like x(i+1), x(i-1)

Comment: You can do it with Spark Udafs. If you are for this option I can show you some code

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 yes, could you please share your idea about this. But I mainly has to do something like x(i+1), x(i-1). If that can be possible with udaf's,  I'll try to implement it, thank you

Comment: the idea behind that is that the udaf can handle your aggregation handling your data with Scala collections. It implies deserialize from dataframe format but you can handle your window in a generic fashion applying a function like f: Seq[(A, C)] => Seq[(A, C)]. I´ll put the code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to treat your Spark window-based operations without using the spark Window and Spark sql functions you can do it with UDAFs. Working with UDAFs and UDFs is something that in some blogs encourage to not use them unless it is necessary. But, if you can afford to loss some performance and maybe bigger GC pauses maybe you can make an attempt to play with your custom Spark transformations/aggregations.

The example:

suppose you want to perform and some slide window in your dataset which can be represented as:

```
item: String, key: String, timestamp: Long, field1:String, field2:Int, field3:Int, field4:Int
```

And you want, for example, to implement the increment of **field2** as a new field of your dataframe, and you want to do it without using Spark sql and you need to use the Scala type system, for example, you want to perform the operation between two rows using a **Monoid** instance. Maybe it is better to work directly RDD in this case... The following could be an example of how to deal with Dataframe api.

Working with dataframes and Scala types at the same time is a little bit cumbersome because you have to deal with both family types:

You must implement UDAFs abstract members:

```
class GenericAggregate(id: StringType, in: IntegerType, sort: LongType, output:IntegerType)(f: Seq[(String, Int)] => Seq[(String, Int)]) {

  private val mapType = MapType(id, MapType(sort, output, true), true)

  // This is the schema for your UDAF. The aggregation needs three fields from the input dataframe
  override def inputSchema: StructType =
    StructType(
      StructField("id_schema0", id) :: StructField("sort_schema0", sort) :: StructField(
        "input_schema0",
        in) :: Nil)

   // This is the internal fields you keep for computing your aggregate. 
  override def bufferSchema: StructType =
    StructType(StructField("internal_buffer", mapType) :: Nil)
  }

  // This kind of aggregation returns a key-value: key -> delta
  override def dataType: DataType = MapType(id, output)

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  // This is the initial value for your buffer schema.
  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
   buffer(0) = Map("" -> 0)
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Map[Long, Int]]](0) + (input.getAs[String](0) -> Map(
    input.getAs[Long](1) -> input.getAs[Int](2)))
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[Map[String, Map[Long, Int]]](0) ++ buffer2
     .getAs[Map[String, Map[Long, Int]]](0)
  }


  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val map = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Map[Long, Int]]](0)

    // You need to create a Seq from the map         

    val toSeq0 = map.mapValues(_.head)
    // As window functions you must order your events before applying the function
    val toSeq1 = toSeq0.toSeq.sortBy(_._2._1)
    val sequence = toSeq1.map(el => (el._1, el._2._2))

    /*
    For example, if your internal map is val in = 
        Map("ke1" -> Map(1L -> 3), "key2" -> Map(2L -> 3))
        you will get ArrayBuffer((ke1,3), (key2,3))
    */

    val result = f(sequence)  

    /*
       As a result you will have another ArrayBuffer with your new data
       Map("ke1" -> Map(1L -> 1), "key2" -> Map(2L -> 1))
    */
    result.toMap - k.initKey
  }

}
```

In this example a Map is used to create the aggregation, but you need to provide the function that operates on this collection and returns a new field.

Why is it necessary?, well, in case you need to abstract or build a DSL over Spark Sql with more complex types you could use type class derivation to build your custom window/aggregation functions for your products. But, as I said before, **working directly with Spark SQL functions is highly recommended the most of the times**. These alternatives help to understand much better how Spark works and give the opportunity to play with the compiler in order to build more generic data pipelines or even to create DSLs that can be executed over Spark Sql.

Hope this helps.